# Ajax GET request response missing data field

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I make a GET request to my backend Rails application from my React component and receive a successful response (200) however I am missing data attribtue in the respose object holding the list of objects from the database. Here's my Ajax request

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/dashboard/jobs/eligible',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: (response) => {
    console.log(response)
  }
});
```

When I do console.log(response.data) I get 'undefined'. I get an Array of one object from the backend, though.

`console.log(response) # [{...}]` which holds one object from database.

Here's my `dashboard/jobs` controller action:

```
def eligible
    @eligible_jobs = EligibleJobsDatatable.new(current_user).call

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js { render json: @eligible_jobs }
    end
end
```

I don't use any serializers in the project.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: Have you tried using a tool like postman to see what the response it from the API? Does the data come back as expected there?

Comment: try `format.json` instead of `format.js`

Comment: I get the expected data from backend, it's just that I don't have `data` field in Ajax `response`

Comment: `format.json` returns same response.

Comment: write "debugger" before console.log and see what is inside response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response is correct. It is a serialized object.

However, I believe that you need a response that follows [jsonapi](https://jsonapi.org) standard. If that's true, I suggest you use a gem that will handle serialization of your object into JSON, i.e. [fast_jsonapi](https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi).

Comment: I've just updated my `call` method to return { data: data } and it now works. Strange, though, I thought that Ajax returns `data` field always by default.

Comment: No, you decide what is returned :)

Answer (score 1):

> When I do console.log(response.data) I get 'undefined'. I get an Array of one object from the backend, though.

This is how it should work.

From the Ajax Documentation:

> **success**
>
> Type: *Function( Anything data, String textStatus, jqXHR jqXHR
>   )* A function to be called if the request succeeds. The function gets
>   passed three arguments: The data returned from the server, formatted
>   according to the dataType parameter or the dataFilter callback
>   function, if specified; a string describing the status; and the jqXHR
>   (in jQuery 1.4.x, XMLHttpRequest) object.

The Ajax request accepts a data parameter, a textStatus, and the request object. If you want those, create your function like this:

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/dashboard/jobs/eligible',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: (data, status, obj) => {
    console.log(data)
  }
});
```